# How to get products grouped by category ID in TypeORM?

Tags: php, node.js, typeorm, nodejs-server, node.js-typeorm

Hi, I'm trying to get a list of products grouped by category id, but I don't understand how to apply it.

These are my entities

```
@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  name: string;
  @Column()
  url_image: string;
  @Column()
  price: number;
  @Column()
  discount: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, (category) => category.products)
  category: Category;
}


@Entity()
export class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Product, (product) => product.category)
  products: Product[];
}
```

I am trying to use Query Builder, but can't find a way to get it.